Cannot figure out how to compile assembly in Visual Studio 2024
I am attempting to compile assembly for x86 using an empty c++ repository. I am new to assembly and am just trying to get a basic program to work so I can tell if my assembly code works or not.
This is related to a question asked about assembly, but and all they say is to set custom build info to masm. I did that and it doesn't change anything.
I'm not interested in manually running commands to get a simple assembly script to work.
Here's my code:
.386                      ; Use 32-bit instructions
.model flat, stdcall      ; Flat memory model and stdcall calling convention
.stack 4096               ; Define stack size

.code                     ; Code section

extern ExitProcess   ; Declare ExitProcess as an external function

start:
    mov eax, 255          ; Load the exit code (255) into the eax register
    push eax              ; Push the exit code onto the stack
    call ExitProcess      ; Call ExitProcess to exit the program

end start                 ; End of program


How is that relevant to C++?

I edited out the C++ tag because I see no evidence that it's relevant.

im trying to compile assembly code in a c++ empty repo...

That doesn't mean C++ experts following the [c++] tag will be able to help you.  Just the mention of what kind of VS project you're using belongs in the question body, not tags.

You need to create custom build step. which is shown in this answer. In addition if you use printf or scanf, you'll need: includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib, since VS now defaults to creating an entry program in a C | C++ compiled object which won't exist in an assembly only project.

As far as I'm aware, there is no Visual Studio 2024; the latest is still Visual Studio 2022.

In addition to custom build step, right click on the asm source file, properties, general, and set excluded from build from "no" to blank or "yes".
